# How to add data-format="DD-MM-YYYY" data-template="D MMM YYYY" to @Html.TextBoxFor razor syntax

Tags: asp.net-mvc, date, razor

I have this line in razor syntax

```
 @Html.TextBoxFor(model => Model.Contact.DateOfBirth,
                  new
                  {
                      type = "text",
                      id = "date ",
                      name = "date",
                      value="09-01-2013"
                  });
```

How to add this attribute `data-format="DD-MM-YYYY" data-template="D MMM YYYY"` inside `@Html.TextBoxFor`?

Answer (score 1):

I assume that your problem comes from using the minus sign. Razor interprets this as a subtraction and tries to find the two variables ("data" and "format", for example"). Luckily you have the `RouteValueDictionary` class:

```
@{
     RouteValueDictionary<string, object> myHtmlOptions= new RouteValueDictionary<string, object>();
     myHtmlOptions.Add("type", "text");
     myHtmlOptions.Add("id", "date");
     myHtmlOptions.Add("name", "date");
     myHtmlOptions.Add("value", "09-01-2013");
     myHtmlOptions.Add("data-format", "DD-MM-YYYY");
     myHtmlOptions.Add("data-template", "D MMM YYYY");
}

@Html.TextBoxFor(model => Model.Contact.DateOfBirth, myHtmlOptions)
```

Edit: As Ray Poward mentioned in his answer, using an underscore also works in this scenario. Although this is a faster and more convenient way of passing Html Options, the internal structure of these helpers prefers the use of `RouteValueDictionary`. If you pass an `object`, the MVC framework will convert it to a `RouteValueDictionary` automatically.

Answer (score 1):

Simply using an underscore worked for me:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => Model.Contact.DateOfBirth,
    new
    {
        type = "text",
        id = "date ",
        name = "date",
        value="09-01-2013",
        data_format="DD-MM-YYYY",
        data_template="D MMM YYYY"
    });
```

Answer (score -1):

The same way like you did for all of the other attributes

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => Model.Contact.DateOfBirth,
    new
    {
        type = "text",
        id = "date ",
        name = "date",
        value="09-01-2013",
        data_format="DD-MM-YYYY",
        data_template="D MMM YYYY"
     });
```

But keep in mind that in this implementation you should have additional JavaScript logic to handle the data-format and data-template attribute. The above code shows only how to add the two attributes to the input

Comment: Try that and tell me if Razor complains about the minus sign.

Comment: It should be apparent, but it's not always so simple. If you think about it, that's an anonymous object with properties and their names must follow the same naming rules as any other variable/property of a "regular" object.